# Qt Android Deployment Failing

Tags: android, qt, qtandroidextras

I have tried to modify the Android template files according to the documentation listed [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-android.html)

In my .pro file I have the following:

```
ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = Android_Files
```

And my directory structure looks like this:

```
QtProject
|-- Android_Files
|   |-- AndroidManifest.xml
|
|-- Resources
|-- Source
|-- Application.pro
|-- Application.pro.user
```

But when my Qt Creator goes to deploy the application, I get the following error:

```
Cannot find android sources in Android_Files
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android`

Comment: I imagine you mean `ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/Android_Files` for my case?

Comment: Yes Please try it.

Comment: That sure worked! Did I miss something in the documentation or is that something missing from Qt's documentation?

Comment: If you post that as an answer I'll accept it as correct so you get credit.

Comment: Thanks. glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android package directory is not right.

Use $PWD to refer to the current project directory

```
ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/Android_Folder_Name
```

in your case: `$$PWD/Android_Files`

More info about PWD:

[The PWD variable specifies the full path leading to the directory containing the current file being parsed. This can be useful to refer to files within the source tree when writing project files to support shadow builds.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#pwd)